# Updating to the latest commit in branch without rebuilding satis

Tags: git, composer-php, satis

I recently started using the Composer repository generator Satis for hosting my own private packages.

What I find a bit annoying is that during development of a project, which is using some of the repositories generated by the Satis, I always have to rebuild the satis when I push some new commit into the package repository.

Eg. I have something like this in the composer.json of the project, where I'm using the package:

```
"require": {
    "test/package": "dev-master"
}
```

Now when I build the Satis, latest commit in the master branch of the package repository was **A**, but in the meanwhile I had to push another commit into the package repository **B**. Now to get the **B** commit in the project, I have to first build the Satis and then of course also use composer update on the project.

Is there some solution for this? Can I either somehow force it in the composer.json of the project or maybe set up Satis differently.

I understand that I have to rebuild it when I add some new tag or branch there and that's fine, but having to build it after each commit gets a bit annoying.

Comment: Face with same problem we're directly cloning repos what we need to develop.